# Sencha Cmd - Unknown command: include

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

**Hi everybody,**

**The problem is sencha cmd give this error : Unknown command include**

**I working in Ext Js 4.2**

ruby -v
  -- ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]

compass -v   -> Compass 0.12.5 (Alnilam)

sencha cmd version : 4.0.4.84

**What is your solution ?**

**Thanks everyboy**

---

```
command line code :

cd D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList

sencha app refresh

 Error output here : 

> Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84 [INF]  [INF] init-plugin: [INF]  [INF]
> cmd-root-plugin.init-properties: [INF]  [INF] init-properties: [INF] 
> [INF] init-sencha-command: [INF]  [INF] init: [INF]  [INF]
> app-refresh: [INF]      [echo] Refreshing app at
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList [INF]  [INF] app-refresh-impl: [INF] 
> [INF] -before-init-local: [INF]  [INF] -init-local: [INF]  [INF]
> -after-init-local: [INF]  [INF] init-local: [INF]  [INF] find-cmd-in-path: [INF]  [INF] find-cmd-in-environment: [INF]  [INF]
> find-cmd-in-shell: [INF]  [INF] init-cmd: [INF]      [echo] Using
> Sencha Cmd from C:\Users\SARGIN.A-SARGIN\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.4.84 for
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\build.xml [INF]  [INF] -before-init:
> [INF]  [INF] -init: [INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
> [INF] Adding antlib taskdef for
> com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml [INF]  [INF] -after-init:
> [INF]  [INF] -before-init-defaults: [INF]  [INF] -init-defaults: [INF]
> [INF] -after-init-defaults: [INF]  [INF] -init-compiler: [INF]  [INF]
> init: [INF]  [INF] refresh: [INF]  [INF] -before-refresh: [INF]  [INF]
> -init: [INF]  [INF] -init-compiler: [INF]  [INF] -detect-app-build-properties: [INF] Loading app json manifest... [INF] Loading classpath entry D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\src [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-base\src [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-base\overrides
> [INF] Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-neutral\src [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-neutral\overrides
> [INF] Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-neptune\src [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\packages\ext-theme-neptune\overrides
> [INF] Loading classpath entry D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\app [INF]
> Loading classpath entry D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\app.js [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\build\temp\production\Exp\sencha-compiler\app
> [INF] Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\build\temp\production\Exp\sencha-compiler\app
> [WRN] unable to locate files for external reference :
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\ext\ext-theme-neptune.js [WRN] scope is
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\build\temp\production\Exp\sencha-compiler\app
> [INF] Concatenating output to file
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList/build/temp/production/Exp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
> [INF] Adding external reference : @full-page => @overrides [INF]
> Loading classpath entry
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\build\temp\production\Exp\sencha-compiler\cmd-packages.js
> [INF] Adding external reference : Ext.util.Observable =>
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList/build/temp/production/Exp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
> [INF]  [INF] -refresh-app: [INF] Appending concatenated output to file
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList/bootstrap.js [ERR]  [ERR] BUILD FAILED
> [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExArg: Unknown command: "include" [ERR] 
> [ERR] Total time: 5 seconds [ERR] The following error occurred while
> executing this line:
> C:\Users\SARGIN.A-SARGIN\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.4.84\plugins\ext\4.2\plugin.xml:386:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:367: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\.sencha\app\refresh-impl.xml:100: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> D:\Proje\SenchaExtJs\TaskList\.sencha\app\refresh-impl.xml:44:
> com.sencha.exceptions.ExArg: Unknown command: "include"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is OS Language.

I use Windows 8.1 Turkish.  I installed United States English and change my operating system language US ENG after restart the computer.

the error going to hell :)

reference page :

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?261919-Sencha-Cmd-3.1.1-Error-while-building-new-theme/page2

Comment: Please check my answer, I think it's better than changing OS language.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this vm arguments fixed that issue:
**your_sencha_path\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6\sencha.vmoptions**

```
-Duser.country=US
-Duser.language=en 
-Duser.variant=Traditional_WIN
```